# illegal state exception Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: android, retrofit2

Hey Guys please help me out! I am stuck in this error which is very persistent. I am unable to understand why is the error happening. Please help me out guys. I am using retrofit 2.0.0

This is the error:
failed Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

this is the stack trace:

```
07-11 10:30:38.393 26263-26263/com.example.kick.imageslider D/ViewRootImpl: doProcessInputEvents ViewRoot{3c3c6ba com.example.kick.imageslider/com.example.kick.imageslider.login_register,ident = 1}
07-11 10:30:38.394 26263-26263/com.example.kick.imageslider D/View: Touch up dispatch to android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{ecc3188 VFED..C.. ...p.... 0,1361-840,1505 #7f0c00ed app:id/btn_register}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=425.49493, y[0]=41.232178, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=769988827, downTime=769988788, deviceId=7, source=0x1002 }
07-11 10:30:38.394 26263-26263/com.example.kick.imageslider D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
07-11 10:30:38.401 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider I/System.out: [CDS][DNS] getAllByNameImpl netId = 0
07-11 10:30:38.403 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=hostmyfile.16mb.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
07-11 10:30:38.403 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
07-11 10:30:38.404 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=hostmyfile.16mb.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
07-11 10:30:38.404 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
07-11 10:30:38.408 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: hostmyfile.16mb.com get result from proxy gai_error = 0
07-11 10:30:38.409 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:90000
07-11 10:30:38.409 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider I/System.out: [socket][7] connection hostmyfile.16mb.com/31.170.165.198:80;LocalPort=50547(90000)
07-11 10:30:38.409 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider I/System.out: [CDS]connect[hostmyfile.16mb.com/31.170.165.198:80] tm:90
07-11 10:30:38.409 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider D/Posix: [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.kick.imageslider :80 
07-11 10:30:38.567 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider I/System.out: [socket][/192.168.1.228:50547] connected
07-11 10:30:38.567 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:90000
07-11 10:30:38.716 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider I/System.out: [CDS][DNS] getAllByNameImpl netId = 0
07-11 10:30:38.716 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=error.hostinger.eu; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
07-11 10:30:38.716 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
07-11 10:30:38.717 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=error.hostinger.eu; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
07-11 10:30:38.718 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
07-11 10:30:38.724 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: error.hostinger.eu get result from proxy gai_error = 0
07-11 10:30:38.724 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:90000
07-11 10:30:38.724 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider I/System.out: [socket][8] connection error.hostinger.eu/31.170.160.61:80;LocalPort=47182(90000)
07-11 10:30:38.724 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider I/System.out: [CDS]connect[error.hostinger.eu/31.170.160.61:80] tm:90
07-11 10:30:38.724 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider D/Posix: [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.kick.imageslider :80 
07-11 10:30:38.954 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider I/System.out: [socket][/192.168.1.228:47182] connected
07-11 10:30:38.954 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:90000
07-11 10:30:39.182 26263-31413/com.example.kick.imageslider I/System.out: close [socket][/192.168.1.228:47182]
07-11 10:30:39.195 26263-26263/com.example.kick.imageslider D/Beeetle: failedUse JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
```

this is my POJO:

```
public class User {


    @Expose
    private String name;


    @Expose
    private String email;


    @Expose
    private String password;


    @Expose
    private String homeaddress;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setHomeaddress(String homeaddress) {
        this.homeaddress = homeaddress;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getHomeaddress() {
        return homeaddress;
    }
}
```

This is my registration method:

```
private void registerProcess(String name, String email,String password,String homeaddress){

        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        client.readTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        client.connectTimeout(90,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client.build())
                .build();

        RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

        User user = new User();
        user.setName(name);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.setHomeaddress(homeaddress);
        ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
        request.setOperation(Constants.REGISTER_OPERATION);
        request.setUser(user);
        Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);

        response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

                ServerResponse resp = response.body();
                Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                //goToLogin();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Log.d(Constants.TAG,"failed"+t.getLocalizedMessage());
                Snackbar.make(getView(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer:

You are set for getting object from response but the response is something different like string.So check again your response in browser that it have json object as a starting point.

Comment: @Sidharth , Yr wlcm if this helps then please upvote this answer so other user can also get help.Thankyou